# how to loop over a list in json format

Tags: python

I have the following input in variable "text", I want to loop of each value in the list "text" and print the number, and I am getting a syntax error when trying the following, can anyone provide input on what is wrong here?

```
text = [{u'isCurrentPatchSet': True, u'revision': u'52f0d3ae2dcfce2dcae11f5b72cd15dfd19b2d78', u'ref': u'refs/changes/19/352319/1', u'id': u'I02c3e5df67d8f3b6e5b217f3910b503c061a9f5d', u'number': u'352319'}, {u'isCurrentPatchSet': True, u'revision': u'52f0d3ae2dcfce2dcae11f5b72cd15dfd19b2d78', u'ref': u'refs/changes/20/325320/6', u'id': u'I02c3e5df67d8f3b6e5b217f3910b503c061a9f5d', u'number': u'325320'}]
for num in text[i]['number']
    print num
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `:` after your `for` loop.

Here's what you should do:

```
for element in text:
    print element['number']
```

Or with list comprehension:

```
for number in [element['number'] for element in text]:
    print number
```